# Accept user input in capital or lower case

Tags: java

How can i make java accept user input in capital or lower case? I tried using equalsIgnoreCase() but i didn't work.

```
System.out.println("Rock, Paper Or Scissor?");
user = input.next().equalsIgnoreCase();

System.out.println("You entered: " + user); 

System.out.println("Computer entered: " + computer);

//user options
if(user.equals("rock") && computer.equals("rock"))
{
    System.out.println("Play again!");
}
else if(user.equals("rock") && computer.equals("scissor"))
{
    System.out.println("You won!");
}
```

Comment: That's a comparison method. You could use `.toLowerCase()` to convert all input to lower case.

Comment: Thanks. The option .toLowerCase() worked.

Answer (score 1):

[String::equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) takes a `String` and return a `boolean` :

> `public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)`

So `equalsIgnoreCase` should be used like this :

```
if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && computer.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
```

And

```
if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && computer.equalsIgnoreCase("scissor"))
```

Not like this :

```
user = input.next().equalsIgnoreCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The option .toLowerCase() worked.

```
  System.out.println("Rock, Paper Or Scissor?");
            user = input.next().toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("You entered: " + user); 

            System.out.println("Computer entered: " + computer);

            //user options
            if(user.equals("rock") && computer.equals("rock"))
            {
                System.out.println("Play again!");
            }
            else if(user.equals("rock") && computer.equals("scissor"))
            {
                System.out.println("You won!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
user = input.next().toLowerCase();
```